# How do I use COM objects in an OOB Silverlight 4.0 application?

Tags: com, silverlight-4.0, activex, silverlight-oob

I am contemplating building an out of browser Silverlight application.  One of the reasons it has to be OOB is because I need to access an old school ActiveX/COM object and that is only allowed OOB.

I am having trouble finding any examples on how to actually integrate a COM object into a Silverlight app.  The Add References dialog does not have a COM tab so I am lost.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff457794%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) can help you.

Best